# Select first element in dropdown in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am getting content of dropdown list as a `Map<number, string>`. When I get the map, it is received sorted according to keys in ascending order.
While showing it in html, I am setting pipe keyvalue and provided a function to sort the items in ascending order of values.

Now, I am trying to select first element of this dropdown, but unable to do so.
I have tried jQuery method to select the first element.
I have tried to set ngModel of the select box to first value of the map, but it sets the value to the first value received in the Map which is sorted by key.

```
My HTML:
<select class="form-control" id="empId" [(ngModel)]="empId" [disabled]="!isEditable">
    <option *ngFor="let emp of empNames | keyvalue:descOrder" [value]="emp.key">{{ emp.value }}</option>
</select>
```

```
 My ts file:

    this.commonService.getEmployeeList())
          .subscribe((response) => {
              this.empNames = response;
              this.empId = this.empNames.keys().next().value;
    });
```

```
data I am sending from server is:
{id:1,name: "Tim"},
{id:6,name: "Martha"},
{id:5,name: "Alex"},
{id:8,name: "Stacy"}
```

```
data I am receiving on screen is like:
Alex
Martha
Stacy
Tim

with Tim pre-selected
```

what I need is Alex should be pre-selected.

Comment: I don't get it. you say you want the value's in ascending order but have the keyvalue:descOrder. I assume descOrder orders the strings in descending order!? Can you post it?

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcc5mz)

```
<option *ngFor="let emp of empNames | keyvalue:descOrder" [value]="emp.key" [selected]="emp.id === 1">{{ emp.value }}</option>
```

you can use selected `attribute` like above

Answer (score 1):

Then set the empId before subscribing.

```
 this.empId = 5;

this.commonService.getEmployeeList())
      .subscribe((response) => {
          this.empNames = response;
     });
```

Of course you might want another logic based on some kind of order. You can never be sure how the data are going to be received.

In this case you need to send the order from your api and filter by order.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pre select an option is to use `ngModel` as you tried. Your list is sorted by keys so what you want is not to select the first item, yes it's the first but in other order so or you change the order in code or you search for the item you want to select and stores it to set on model.

I would suggest some changes that should improve the code and fix your problem.

```
<select class="form-control" id="empId" [(ngModel)]="currentEmployer" [disabled]="!isEditable">
    <option *ngFor="let emp of employers$ | async" [value]="emp">{{ emp.value }}</option>
</select>
```

And order your list in a pipe with the function you prefer.

```
public currentEmployer: Employer = null;

private sortByNameAscending(e1, e2) {
    return e1.name > e2.name ? 1 : 0;
}

this.employers$ = this.commonService.getEmployeeList().pipe(
    switchMap(employers => {
        const sortedList = employers.sort(this.sortByNameAscending);
        if (sortedList.length > 0) {
            this.currentEmployer = sortedList[0];
        }
        return sortedList;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommand you to use Angular's reactive forms! And set the select's value to the one you want, when you recieve your data. Don't use ngModel as it is deprecated and should have been removed by Angular 7 (Or will be soon). Check [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)